# Custom Kickstart ISO process - packages to RPM mapping

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart

I want to start by saying that I am new to kickstart so if I use the wrong terms I apologize in advance.

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
I am trying to create a customer ISO for installation of CentOS and a web-based application that I wrote.  I want to create an "appliance" type install to make it easy to deploy a VM or bare-metal server running the application and nothing else.

I have an example ISO that is made by another company, based on RHEL, and I am trying to follow what they have done and customize it to my needs.

**Question:**
I am looking at the ks.cfg file in the example iso I have it defines the packages to be installed, which I believe is ultimately the list of RPMs from directories in the root of the ISO. Below is an excerpt from the ks.cfg file:

```
#Package install information
%packages
@ base
@ core
@ acme-base
@ acme-platform
@ acme-application
```

Looking at the directories on the iso i believe @acme-platform is going to cause the installation of /acme/acmeplatform/RPMS/*.rpm

My question is how this mapping is defined from @acme-platform to the directory on the ISO where the actual RPMs are stored.

EDIT: After reading the first answer I wanted to clarify the question: i am really looking for what file maps the location of the RPMs to the groups that are referenced in the `ks.cfg` file.  I see that the actual packages that make up the groups are defined in `/repodata/comps.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The packages listed are actually `yum` package groups. Groups are used to that they don't have to list out the individual packages (or necessarily know which packages are recommended for a particular effect) manually. For example, on RHEL 6 (and I would presume CentOS 6) if you're text-only you can do `yum groupinstall Desktop` which installs all the packages required to satisfy the group called "Desktop" which ultimately ends up installing the GNOME desktop and miscellaneous applications Red Hat thought you'd find useful. That's to make the process as simple as basically saying "I want a desktop."

The `core` and `base` groups are part of the RHEL/CentOS base, the `acme-*` groups are probably for the appliance in question. They probably put the rpm's in the same directory

I would start by mounting [creating a yum repo that looks at the ISO mounted on loopback](http://www.unixmen.com/add-dvd-to-yum-repository-in-centos-6/) then issuing the `yum groupinfo` commands required to see which individual packages go with each of the groups. For example, to see the packages in the `base` group you would type `yum groupinfo base` and behold the glory.

The package names it gives will be for RPM's located on the DVD somewhere (can't remember but I think there's an "RPMS" directory) with the package name forming the first part of the RPM's filename.

For example, if you see a package called `btparser` the filename might be called `btparser-0.17-2.el6.x86_64.rpm` (I would just issue a `find /path/to/mountedISO -name 'btparser*` to locate it, though).

That should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Joel, I understand that these are yum packages and I apologize if I did not make that clear in my original question.  I am really looking for what file does the mapping of where the RPMS are stored since the name of the package is not a direct map to directory on the ISO.

Comment: My explanation says that these are NOT package names, they're package _group_ names. You need to do the `yum groupinfo` on each group to get a list of the actual packages that go along with these groups.

Comment: RPM requires the file follow a strict [naming convention](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html), meaning the file has to begin with the package name.

Comment: Got it, sorry i meant to type groups.  I updated the question to try to clarify.  I understand that the packages are in groups that are defined in comps.xml file in repodata dir.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/yum.conf and .repo files in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ determine which repos to use. In these repos there is a file repodata/primary.xml that specifies the location (via the "location" field) of the RPMs.

You probably don't want to integrate your software into the main CD repo. I'd create it elsewhere in the iso and use creatrepo. In the kickstart configuration you can add "repo" commands to add this repo using, e.g., "repo --name=acme --baseurl=file://mnt/cdrom/local/repos/acme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark, I do see the `repodata/primary.xml.gz` file on the ISO, and when i extract primary.xml from it I see locations for all of the RH RPMs but I don't see any reference to the application RPMs.  Also, there is not `repo` lines in the `ks.cfg` file.  Any additional thoughts on where this would be?

Comment: If you add RPMs to the repo you need to regenerate the metadata with `createrepo`. However, as I said, I wouldn't mess with the RHEL repo. I'd create my open repo. If you did that, you'd need to add a `repo ...` line to the ks file to enable use of tht repo.